# Using CSS module in React where NPM package expects global import

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, parceljs

I have a React app, I am building this app using [ParcelJS](https://parceljs.org/). In this app I have included an NPM package ([zalify/easy-email](https://github.com/zalify/easy-email)) which styles its component by using a CSS import:

```
import "@arco-themes/react-easy-email-theme/css/arco.css";
```

The import overwrites some of my styles since [Parcel treats all css imports as global imports](https://parceljs.org/languages/css/#css-modules):

> By default, CSS imported from JavaScript is global. If two CSS files define the same class names, ids, custom properties, @keyframes, etc., they will potentially clash and overwrite each other. To solve this, Parcel supports CSS modules.

I'd like to not have my styles overridden. According to the [Parcel docs](https://parceljs.org/languages/css/#css-modules) I can use CSS modules for this. They state:

> To use CSS modules, create a file with the .module.css extension, and import it from a JavaScript file with a namespace import. Then, you can access each of the classes defined in the CSS file as an export from the module.

```
import * as classes from './styles.module.css';

document.body.className = classes.body;
```

Is there a way to pass the imported CSS module to the component that expects the CSS import without having to edit the component? The component from the NPM package expects the style as global style, not a CSS module.

I have tried to import the style using `require` in the functional component instead but the css is still loaded globally.

Comment: *Is there a way to pass the imported CSS module to the component that expects the CSS import without having to edit the component?* - not really

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just adjusting the style with more specific selectors.